# String inclusion in Fish Shell

Tags: fish

I've looked at all the similar questions on Stack Overflow, and tried a bunch of stuff in their documentation. My present attempt is below.

What I'm trying to accomplish is differential behavior based on the computer user. I have a work computer and a home computer, and I want the work computer to go to a different directory when I enter "code" into the command line than the one I want when I enter it at home. I tried this (my work username is afk, home is sfk):

```
function code
    set result (dirh)
    if [contains "sfk" $result]
        cd ~/rails
    else if [contains "afk" $result]
        cd ~/code
    else
        echo $result
    end
end
```

Currently, this is griping that "Unknown command contains Users/sfk/.config/fish/" (My PWD is Users/sfk/.config/fish/ when I'm entering this). I think maybe contains is just for lists, but the docs aren't particularly clear about this? Any idea how I might do this?

**EDIT**

Just tried this, and while it no longer errors, it ends up in the else case, which it shouldn't, cause my user IS sfk, which IS included in the dirh string:

```
function code
    set result (dirh)
    if test (contains "sfk" $result)
        cd ~/rails
    else if test (contains "afk" $result)
        cd ~/code
    else
        echo $result
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't get it? If you have 2 different users then why you do not simply create 2 separate `code` functions?

Comment: Longish answer - because 90% of my fish functions are the same, I have them on github, so I can sync any new fish functionality between my two computers, so they behave identically, but THIS function differs between them, so rather than try to have .gitignored files with computer-specific functions, I was hoping to just have the function behave differently based on the computer username

Comment: Have you thought about setting global env variable that will specify path to folder what you need and, i.e. creating in your home file `.configrc` and load it in your `fish.config`. It will be more universal that this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said above in the comments, that is the best solution for this specific use case. But to answer the question in case someone wants to do something else.

You are right about `contains`, that it does an exact match on list items. You could use the `switch` function instead. Which supports wild-card matching.

```
function code
    set -l result (dirh)

    switch $result
        case '*sfk*'
            cd ~/rails
        case '*afk*'
            cd ~/code
        case '*'
            echo $result
    end
end
```